# set dynamic computed property in decorator VueJs Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a component that looks like this:

```
@Component({
    computed: {
        [this.stateModel]: {
            get() {
                return this.$store[this.stateModel];
            }
        }
    }
})
class Component extends Vue{
    @Prop({ default: '' }) private stateModel!: string;
}
```

Which I'm trying is bind `stateModel` as a property when I use this component. `stateModel` should be a field in the state and could be injected into the component. Typescript is throwing me an error that said:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

I tried to make an Interface and set it as computed, but it didn't work.

Any help is highly appreciate it.

Comment: If `stateModel` is a prop, are you trying to update the value of stateModel with that from the store when stateModel prop changes?

Comment: Hi @Tony, what I'm trying to do is inject a name property `stateModel` of the state

Comment: Did the watcher work for you?

Comment: @Tony No, it didn't. stateModel is not a property, it should be dynamic. I mean, if I use `<Component :stateModel="foo">`, foo should be in the state.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the `this` keyword in a computed property and I got two errors.

> 'this' cannot be referenced in a computed property name

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation

Alternatively, you can use a watcher instead

```js
import { Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
class Component extends Vue{
    ...

    @Watch('stateModel')
    stateModelHasChanged(newValue: number) {
      this.stateModel = this.$store[this.stateModel];
    }
    ...

}
```